# ES5 how to implement .Net IEqualityComaparer on data class for comparisons？

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

When I want to use a custom type `T` as hash key in .Net, I implement [IEqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1) and pass it to hash map like `Dictionary` or `HashSet`, when adding new item, the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` method will be called to check whether two `T` instance are same.

for example, I have a immutable data class `Foo`:

```
sealed class Foo
{
    public Foo(int field1, string field2)
    {
        Prop_1 = field1;
        Prop_2 = field2;
    }

    public int Prop_1 { get; }
    public string Prop_2 { get; }
}
```

and `FooEuqalityComparer`:

```
sealed class FooEuqalityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        return x == null ? y == null :
            x.Prop_1 == y.Prop_1 &&
            x.Prop_2 == y.Prop_2;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return 0;

        return obj.Prop_1.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Prop_2.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

test:

```
var set = new HashSet<Foo>(new FooEuqalityComparer());

var foo1 = new Foo(1, "foo 1");
var not_foo2 = new Foo(1, "foo 1");
var foo3 = new Foo(3, "foo 3");

set.Add(foo1);
set.Add(not_foo2);
Assert.AreEqual(1, set.Count);
Assert.AreSame(foo1, set.Single());

set.Add(foo3);
Assert.AreEqual(2, set.Count);
```

How can I do it in nodejs?

Overwrite `toString()` is not a option because I want to keep reference to that object as key inside map.

---

After some search, I realized that javascript or ECMAScript use [SameValueZero](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevaluezero) algorithm to compare objects, the best way still is using string as key. 
so I use two map to achieve this:

```
class ObjectKeyMap {
  /**
   * @param {Object[]} keys -
   * @param {function():string} keys[].getHashCode -
   * @param {function(Object):T} valueSelector -
   *
   * @typedef {Object} T
   */
  constructor(keys, valueSelector) {
    const keyReferences = {};
    keys.forEach(it => {
      keyReferences[it.getHashCode()] = it;
    });
    this.keyReferences = keyReferences;

    this.map = new Map(keys.map(it => [it.getHashCode(), valueSelector(it)]));
  }

  /**
   * @param {string|{getHashCode:function():string}} key -
   *
   * @returns {string}
   */
  _getStringKey(key) {
    if (!key) {
      return null;
    }

    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(key) === "[object String]") {
      return key;
    } else {
      return key.getHashCode();
    }
  }

  /**
   * @param {string|{getHashCode:function():string}} key -
   *
   * @returns {T}
   */
  get(key) {
    const stringKey = this._getStringKey(key);
    if (!stringKey || stringKey === "") {
      return null;
    }

    return this.map.get(stringKey);
  }

  values() {
    return [...this.map.values()];
  }

  /**
   * @param {string|{getHashCode:function():string}} key -
   */
  key(key) {
    const stringKey = this._getStringKey(key);
    if (!stringKey || stringKey === "") {
      return null;
    }
    return this.keyReferences[stringKey];
  }

  keys() {
    return Object.values(this.keyReferences).slice();
  }
}
```

`ObjectKeyMap` assumes object to be used as key must have a `getHashCode` function which return identity string. It should be more readable if written in TypeScript.

Comment: Your example JS code has `HashSet`, but that's not a builtin thing. Are you asking how to build a custom `HashSet` to do what you want? JS doesn't have custom hashing, so it would be up to you to implement.

Comment: @loganfsmyth No it's C# code...

Comment: Cool, It could have potentially been Typescript or something, so I honestly wasn't sure. So is your question about implementing this in JS? Have you tried anything so far?